# In an observer pattern, is it better to pass data around in the notification, or have the observers reach out to a singleton?

Tags: swift, oop, singleton, observer-pattern, nsnotificationcenter

**Background**

I'm working on an iOS game in Swift which has realtime theme updates. This basically means that SKSpriteObjects change their color when a the theme changes. As I'm implementing it, I'd like to do it in a way that is good OOP practice, and good for scalability (lots of objects doing this at once). I've got two ideas for achieving this:

---

**Method One: Notifier/Observer + Singleton**

-Register all updatable SKSpriteObjects as observers for the key "updateTheme"
-Create a singleton called GameState with the current theme colors
-When the "updateTheme" notification is fired, each of the observers will reach out the the singleton for their new colors.

**Method Two: Notifier/Observer + passed object**

-Register all updatable SKSpriteObjects as observers for the key "updateTheme"
-The object that fires the notification "updateTheme" will create and attach an object to the notification that contains the current theme attributes.
-When the "updateTheme" notification is observed each of the observers will unwrap the object, and then access the updated colors from that unwrapped object.

---

**Question**

Although I think that passing an object around in a notification is a better OOP practice, I'm imagining that all the unwrapping going on won't be the best idea for speed. So with that, I'm more inclined to go for the singleton approach. What are your thoughts? Perhaps there's a better way that I didn't think of to massively update all the objects in my game.

Answer (score 1):

***Never to a singleton.***

Or, to put it in different words:

> Whenever you have two options, and one of them involves a singleton, pick the other option.

My recommendation would be to first write your game *properly*, then see if it suffers performance wise, and if and only if it does, then worry about performance.  And what usually tends to happen is that you will find a few places where you can provide nice and neat *algorithmic* optimizations that will make your game perform better, instead of tweaking and hacking all over the source code to save clock cycles here and there.

That having been said, consider one more alternative:  it is a common pattern with event observers to pass to them as their first parameter a reference to the object issuing the notification.  So, why not have the observable pass a reference to itself to the observers, so that the observers can then obtain whatever they need from the observable?

Comment: I'll go the route of avoiding a singleton and instead pass a reference to an object that will have any information needed by observers. Thanks for the feedback!